# Formatação de campo DateEdit devExpress Windows forms

Tags: c#, devexpress, mask

Galera estou com um problema de formatação de data junto ao componente de data `dateEdit` da `devExpress`. Preciso que a data do campo esteja formatado da seguinte forma: 01/01/2016. E que ao digitar os valores, ir passando para o próximo caractere sem que precise digitar o "/" para passar para o outro campo(mês/ano). Outra restrição é que esse campo deve aceitar valor vazio ou nulo.

Pois quando limpo o campo de data ele coloca uma data inicial que é 01/01/0001, mas deverá ficar com __/ __/____.

Comment: O que você já fez?

Comment: Já tentei varias formas:
- NullText = "MM/dd/yyyy"
  EditFormat = EditFormat.Custom
  EditFormatString = "MMMM dd, yyyy"

- EditFormat = EditFormat.Simple
  EditFormatString = "99/99/9999"
Já tentei varias alternâncias. E nenhuma delas satisfez o q eu precisava.

Comment: Já abriu um chamado na DevExpress? Se você tiver uma licença válida eles respondem em menos de 1 dia. Mas vou tentar responder a pergunta..

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa modificar a máscara de edição:

```
dateEdit1.Properties.Mask.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");
dateEdit1.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "dd/MM/yyyy";
// como você usou 01/01/2016 não dá pra saber se é d/m ou m/d, mude para:
//dateEdit1.Properties.Mask.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
//dateEdit1.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "MM/dd/yyyy";         
dateEdit1.Properties.Mask.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat = true;
dateEdit1.Properties.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
```

Quanto ao valor nulo, eu não consigo reproduzir esse problema aqui na minha máquina. Talvez você tenha modificado o `NullDate`, ou tenha mudado o `AllowNullInput`